# iMac 2009 error when loading after upgrade to Samsung SSD

Tags: macos, mac, ssd, imac

I have upgraded my iMac 2009 to a Samsung 500 SSD. When I boot up the iMac by either holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, I get an image of what appears to be a phone with a toggle; no text:

[image: Mac load error mystery screen image]

What should I do at this screen?

Comment: It's telling you how to turn on a wireless mouse. Do you have a mouse attached to the Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image in the picture is not a phone, but shows the underside of Apple's Magic Mouse.  The image is graphically indicating to the user to turn on the Bluetooth mouse that is paired with the Mac, if it is off.  If you see this graphic, it means that the Mac is not detecting the presence of a mouse, whether a wired USB mouse or a wireless Bluetooth one.